# SQL Query in Oracle where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have table **Groups** with 3 rows, `ID`, `GROUP_NAME` and `PARENT_GROUP_ID`, the table itself presents a basic group-subgroup functionality. Example is: if my Group name is - "First Group" with ID = 1, and it has a subgroup named "Sub Group" with ID = 2, and PARENT_GROUP_ID = 1; this means that **Sub Group** is the subgroup of the group with ID = 1. My problem is that I have a procedure, which loads the data according to parameters(`pn_parent_group_id` is a number)

```
CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT * FROM GROUPS WHERE PARENT_GROUP_ID = pn_parent_group_id;
```

This query works fine when I send any `pn_parent_group_id` into the procedure, and it finds all the necessary subgroups, however when I send NULL to the pn_parent_group_id it works wrong, because it should return those without parent_group_id(meaning only parent groups). I know my explanation is lacking, but I hope you got the idea, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Null is never equal to null. So you need to add an explicit test for null to your cursor.

```
CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT * FROM GROUPS 
     WHERE PARENT_GROUP_ID = pn_parent_group_id
     or (pn_parent_group_id is null and parent_group_id is null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the `SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL` function, which allows the comparison `NULL = NULL` to be `TRUE`.

```
CURSOR c1 IS
   SELECT * FROM GROUPS
   WHERE SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL(parent_group_id) = SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL(pn_parent_group_id);
```

This function is not directly documented in Oracle documentation, but does appear in topic documentation - as it has been around for a long while, I think it unlikely that it will be removed.  As always with these things, use at your own discretion.